# Xcode 4.5.2 - OS X Application - Link webview to code, load hand-coded homepage

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, webview

I am using Xcode 4.5.2.

- I created a new project (OS X > Application > Cocoa Application).
- Under linked Frameworks and Libraries I added Webkit.framework.
- Under MainMenu.xib I added a Web View object to the Window
- Under MainMenu.xib I added 2 Push Buttons and named them Back and Forward.
- I control clicked on the buttons and linked them to the Web View and selected goBack: and goForward:
- Under MainMenu.xib I added a Text Field object
- I control clicked on the text field and linked it to the Web View and selected takeStringURLFrom:

All of that worked. I can enter a web address into the text field and press return and use the back and forward buttons.

I want to hand code a default website (http://www.google.com/) to load and I'm having trouble figuring out what to do from here?

What do I link my web view to (when I control click it)?

What do I need to add to my AppDelgate.h and AppDelgate.m files to load Google into the web view when the app opens?

I did some research and got this far. I was able to find a working example but I am trying to understand how it works step-by-step and am stuck on this step.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your delegate to load the Google homepage after the application launches, you can simply add the following to your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`:

```
NSURL*        url     = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[[self.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
```

This assumes you have the following in your `AppDelegate.h`:

```
@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *webView;
```

which you placed by CTRL-dragging from the `WebView` control in Interface Builder into your `AppDelegate.h`.

Final code:

`AppDelegate.h`

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet WebView *webView;

@end
```

`AppDelegate.m`

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

  NSURL*        url     = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
  NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
  [[self.webView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];

}

@end
```

Comment: I tried control dragging the Web View to the AppDelegate.h file but it does not take?

Comment: I was able to connect the Web View but your code doesn't work.

Comment: Rather than downvoting and saying "it doesn't work" why not provide some useful feedback as to what exactly isn't working?

Comment: I copied and pasted your code above. The error I received is "@synthesize of 'weak' property is only allowed in ARC or GC mode.

Comment: I control clicked the App Delegate object and dragged it to the web view object. That's how I connected it.

Comment: When you set up the project you will want to use ARC (automatic reference counting).  To enable ARC after the project is already set up, go to your Target - Build Settings - and type "ARC" in the search field, you should see under something like 'Apple LLVM Compiler 4.2' a value that says "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" - ensure it says Yes.

Comment: I appreciate your help. I don't get the error now but Google doesn't load.

Comment: If it still isn't loading I would put an NSLog statement in your applicationDidFinishLaunching routine just to ensure its being called (there is no reason it shouldn't if you created a default Cocoa project).  Something like NSLog(@"Beginning loading webview");